# Looping in excel and adds when it satisfies the value

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm trying to write a code in excel vba when

a = 0

And there is a loop, when a condition is satisfied by the cells in the loop, the value of the cell is added to "a"

Currently, when the condition is satisfied, it adds only the value of the first cell which satisfied it but ignores the remaining cells.

Please help!

Comment: please elaborate the question.

Comment: Show _current_ code

Answer (score 0):

It adds only the first cell value to variable (a) because the condition will not be true after that (a<>0) so it will not continue through the loop, if you want to keep using a condition then add cells values to another variable (ex: b)